# Simple proof explanation - Possibly triangle inequality involved

Tags: matrices, inequality, summation, absolute-value, proof-explanation

I'd like some help with understanding the following statements...I saw it on the internet while searching for a proof, and I'd like to understand why its true:

let $A$ be a diagonally dominant matrix with respect to the columns (meaning $|a_{jj}|$ is larger than the sum of the absolute values of the entries in column $j$).

Then:

$$\sum_{i=2,i\neq j}^{n} |a_{ij}-\frac{a_{1j}a_{i1}}{a_{11}}| \leq \sum_{i=2,i\neq j}^{n}|a_{ij}|+\sum_{i=2,i\neq j}^{n}|\frac{a_{1j}a_{i1}}{a_{11}}| \leq (|a_{jj}-|a_{1j}|)+\frac{|a_{1j}|(|a_{11}|-|a_{j1}|}{|a_{11}}$$

which is equal to

$$|a_{jj}-\frac{a_{j1}a_{1j}}{a_{11}}|$$

Firstly, I don't understand why the first inequality is true. And even if it was, I don't understand how the second one follows (it should follow from $A$ being diagonally dominant), and I don't understand why the last term in the inequality is equal to what I wrote after "which is equal to".

Would really appreciate help understanding this part,

Comment: The first inequality comes from directly applying the triangle inequality, follwed by the associativity of the sum of real numbers. The next inequality looks like it comes from the diagonal dominance, but proving it isn't necessarily immediate (some intermediate steps might be missing). Although, it's unclear what the $j$ indices represent at that point seeing as there's no summation...

Comment: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/acm106a/Hw/hw2sol.pdf Maybe this will help. this is where I found the proof. bottom of first page. I'd like to understand how first inequality follows from triangle inequality. triangle inequality means $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$. I don't see how that applies here.

Comment: Put $x = a_{ij}$ and $y = -\frac{a_{1j}a_{i1}}{a_{11}}$.